# Has lunar opposition surge ever been observed from Earth? From Earth orbit?

Tags: the-moon, astrophysics, optics, apparent-magnitude, planetary-science

This [thorough answer to *How long does lunar opposition surge last? Are there measurements of the full Moon getting suddenly brighter?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/43187/7982) details observations of lunar opposition surge by the [Clementine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clementine_(spacecraft)) and [Lunar Reconnaissance orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Reconnaissance_Orbiter).

But we don't have to go to lunar orbit to see the sunlit Moon, we can observe the lunar disk right here on Earth.

**Question:** Has lunar opposition surge ever been observed from Earth? From Earth orbit?

Comment: Your first hyperlink contains caption of _this_ question, rather than the linked one.

Comment: @Ruslan ah I see, thanks! Feel free to edit errors anytime yourself if you feel like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I couldn't find any quantitative information about views from Earth or orbit down to zero phase angle (especially since views direct from Earth are limited in phase angle due to Eclipse), [this website](https://asterism.org/2019/04/12/how-bright-is-the-moon/#:%7E:text=Our%20Moon%27s%20average%20visual%20albedo,dramatically%20as%20its%20phase%20changes.&text=So%20if%20the%20full%20Moon,a%20brightness%20reduction%20of%2012x.) gives an unreferenced data point suggesting Apollo astronauts observed that a zero-phase full moon is approximately 30% (0.2 magnitudes) brighter than we can ever observe from Earth.

[This site](https://the-moon.us/wiki/Retro-Reflection_phenomena) cites a value stating that the moon's brightness at zero phase angle may be as much as 14x brighter than an ideal diffuse reflecting disk, with 40% of the increase within the last 5˚ of phase angle (which cannot be observed from Earth).

Finally, there is [one data set](https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/moon-cal/modeling/irradiance.php) I have found which seems to show the opposition surge effect, but as noted, it is not what I would consider complete, and only has a few data points outside of Earth's viewing capability. That said, the source does not provide a value for maximum reflectance based on their model.

[image: Robotic Lunar Observatory data, Reflectance vs Phase Angle]
Robotic Lunar Observatory data, Reflectance vs Phase Angle

Comment: Really beautiful, thank you very much!

Comment: The "one data set" link is broken